# How to make not only one user be able to use a command containing @tasks.loop discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I have been trying for the past few days now on making my command work for more than one person but it hasn't been working. The command works fine for one person but it cannot work for more than one. Does anyone know how to make a @task.loop work for more than one person? My code is shown below.

```
async def remind(ctx, enabled = "start", interval = 600):
    user = ctx.author
    if enabled.lower() == "deactivate":
        deactivateEmbed = discord.Embed(title = 'I will not remind you to stop procrastinating anymore.', description = 'If you want to activate this again, enter the command pp!remind activate', color = discord.Colour.blue())
        reminder.cancel()
    elif enabled.lower() == "activate":
        remindEmbed = discord.Embed(title = 'Reminding you to stop procrastinating every 10 minutes.', description = 'If you want to deactivate this, enter the command pp!remind deactivate', color = discord.Colour.blue())
        remindEmbed.set_author(name = 'Procrastination Police')
        reminder.change_interval(seconds = int(interval))
        reminder.start(user, remindEmbed)

@tasks.loop(seconds = 600)
async def reminder(user, remindEmbed):
    await user.send(embed=remindEmbed)
```

Answers would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is only one task running and you call it with a user.

Your remind command should register the reminder and then the task should loop through all the reminders.

An alternative could be to have a custom coroutine that uses a while loop to execute the reminder while ending in asyncio.sleep

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering. I tried your method and it worked! There is one problem though. I can't seem to cancel it. I tried using global variables and set it to False to stop the loop when I enter a specific command but it didn't work. Do you possibly have a solution to stop the while loop?

Comment: You want to store tasks somewhere probably a dictionary `Dict[user, List[..., Tasks]` or whatever. Then retrieve the appropriate task and just cancel it. I made an example reminder bot you can check here: https://github.com/chrisdewa/disbots/tree/main/examples/reminder_bot